# Use a temporary variable from jquery function in Angularjs controller

Tags: jquery, angularjs, variables, controller

I need to add to the "order list" the element non only by clicking button but also by user input through input form.
How can I use the var deriving from $click function in controller?

CODE

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('POSController', function ($scope) {
  var x=choose;

  $scope.food = {
    pizza       : {count: 1, id:2, detail: "Brick Oven Pizza", price: 15},
    donut       : {count: 3, id:3, detail: "Glazed Donut",price: 8},
    tortilla    : {count: 1, id:4, detail: "Tortilla Chips",price: 3},
    burger      : {count: 1, id:5, detail: "Burger",price: 3},
    samosa      : {count: 1, id:6, detail: "Delicious Samosas",price: 3},
    coldcoffee  : {count: 1, id:7, detail: "Cold Coffee",price: 2},
    hotcoffee   : {count: 1, id:8, detail: "Hot Coffee",price: 2},
    coke        : {count: 1, id:9, detail: "Coke",price: 2},
    dietcoke    : {count: 1, id:10, detail: "Diet Coke",price: 2},
    pepsi       : {count: 1, id:11, detail: "Pepsi",price: 2},
    incognita: {count: 1, id:12, detail: x, price: 2},
  };

});
```

I need to assign temporary value to variable x of the last element of the array, so that for each input it has the new value.
I attach my PLUNK http://plnkr.co/edit/CoSAgGAco016pEIcRtLi?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added the a button with a ng-click event as follows:

```
<button ng-click='addthisItem(nome)'>Add item</button>
```

then in your controller:

```
$scope.addthisItem = function(nome) {

  if ($scope.food.hasOwnProperty(nome)) {
    $scope.add($scope.food[nome]);
  }
  else {
    //some error handling here
  }
}
```

here is a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/JVmctF3uADHfFkud1w14?p=preview) with the code.

hope it helps.